# Using another OAuth2.0 Authorization Server with MobileFirst Platform other than the included one

Tags: oauth, ibm-mobilefirst, authorization, adfs

reading [this very good blog](https://mfp.help/2015/05/10/getting-familiar-with-ibm-mobilefirst-platform-foundation-oauth-security/) post (Getting familiar with IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation OAuth Security) I learned how MobileFirst Platform (7.0 and above) has an integrated OAuth2.0 Authorization Server, which can be used to protect external resource servers.

However what I would like to understand is **if it's possible to integrate MobileFirst Platform with another Authorization Server** and protect MobileFirst Platform (and external) resource servers. The Authorization Server in this case would be ADFS running on Windows Server 2012R2.

[This document](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/t_datapower_as_authorization_server.html) from the Product Documentation explains how to use DataPower as OAuth Authorization Server. Can it be used also for other OAuth2.0 Authorization servers ? ( The Authorization Server in this case would be ADFS running on Windows Server 2012R2. )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IBMMobileFirst v8.0 **only** has support for Datapower as an **external** authorization server.
If you'd like to use a different AZ server, the only way I can think of is implementing the flow via a MobileFirst [SecurityCheck](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/authentication-and-security/creating-a-security-check/), and have that security check call the other Authorization server. 
That way you'd be using both the MFP AuthorizationServer and ADFS (So two Oauth flows, two tokens etc.).

Think of this high-level flow example:
Your resource is protected by some scope, this scope is mapped to a security check in MobileFirst server. When your client attempts to access the resource, your security check is triggered, which will then make a request to the ADFS authorization flow. Your security check would then act as a middle man between the ADFS and the client, and will be successful only when the ADFS has granted a token. 
Eventually, when the MFP security-check is successful, an MFP Oauth token will be granted to the client, which will allow him to access the protected resource.
So basically your security check will act as your client against the ADFS Authorization server

A more simple way, would be to make that resource unprotected, and implement your own custom Oauth flow against ADFS - but thats not the original question.

But the plus side of the first option, is that you can always make that same scope (which is protecting your resource) be mapped to something else [uninterruptedly](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/setting-up-your-development-environment/console/) (via the console) , like to a different security check which does something else.

---

**For IBM Mobilefirst 7.1 (or 7.0)**, the flow is pretty much the same, only the terminology is different, in 7.x there are no Security checks, but you can use a [Custom authenticator](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/authentication-security/custom-authentication/#customAuth) to get the same functionality.

*Personal note* - If you're not bound to using 7.x, I'd recommend doing it in 8.0